# Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

If I do this...

```
public PriorityQueue(Dispatcher dispatcher = null)
{
    this.dispatcher = dispatcher ?? Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
}
```

And then use it in a ViewModel (without passing any args) that is created through the XAML, `this.dispatcher` will point to the UI thread right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is created from within the UI thread (which it would be, if instantiated inside XAML), then yes, it will point to the UI thread's Dispatcher.